# What parts of asp.net, c# and database should I use to create a forum like stackoverflow?

Tags: asp.net

I am a fresher and I have got a project in asp.net and c#. I have to create a forum, something like stackoverflow, so I have studied asp.net, c# and sql server 2008 but now I am unsure how I should start work on this project.

What technology and what part of asp.net, c# and the database will I use more? I have 3 days to study so I want to know which parts of asp.net, database and c# I have to cover in 3 days.

It's my first live project, will I have to study any other languages or are the ones listed enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use sql server as database / Backend of you application than

start getting infomation about linq to sql >>

[LINQ to SQL: .NET Language-Integrated Query for Relational Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

or you can also go for entity framework

[The ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: sir which one will best i have a basic understanding of ado.net

Comment: i tried linq to sql which works good for my project structure i think at this level you go for linq to sql

Answer (score 3):

Session management, good understanding about `web controls` and `user control`. 
and just go throgh `ado.net` if u are using `asp.net`.
Maybe you should try to use `ASP.net mvc` check this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc).